# Little problem while calculating vertex normals (OpenGL ES)

Tags: opengl-es, light, normals

I'm having a little problem with the vertex normal.

The result seems a little strange. First a look at the images:

**Original model in 3D software.**

[image]

**Per-Fragment lighting, with mesh imported directly from an OBJ file (using normals from file).**

[image]

**Per-Fragment lighting, calculating the normals with my own routine.**

[image]

Did you notice?
Using the normals from OBJ file everything is OK. But when I use my own routine to calculate the normals based on vertices something seems wrong.

The normals seems strange exactly when the Z becomes negative (using a Right-Hand orientation). On the other parts of the object everything is OK, but just one imaginary line across the mesh seems strange. This problem persists on others meshes, always at the same place, the Z = 0.

My routine to calculate the normals is that one, which everyone knows, assuming a triangle with vertices ABC:

```
vec3 normal = normalize(cross(C - A, B - A));
```

And then adding the normal result to an already calculated normal buffer.

I've seen some guys saying about calculate the area of each triangle and multiply it by the normal or even checking against the dot product between the normal on the buffer and the new normal, but I've already tried those approachs and I caught just little changes, but still with the same problem.

Did you seen this before? Do you know how to solve that?

Here is some code:

```
// Looping at each triangle
vec3 distBA = vec3Subtract(vB, vA);
vec3 distCA = vec3Subtract(vC, vA);

vec3 normal = vec3Cross(distBA, distCA);

// Each normalBuffer represents one vertex.
normalBuffer[i1] = vec3Add(normal, normalBuffer[i1]);
normalBuffer[i2] = vec3Add(normal, normalBuffer[i2]);
normalBuffer[i3] = vec3Add(normal, normalBuffer[i3]);

// After pass through all faces/triangles.

// Looping at each Vertex structure.
normal = vec3Normalize(normalBuffer[i]);
```

Comment: Given that the error seems to be per pixel rather than per-polygon, it's possible that the error is somehow in the shader, can you post the code for that as well?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I got why you are _adding_ the normals to the normal buffer rather than just setting them?

Comment: The shaders is the same in both cases (normals from OBJ and calculated by me). With normals from OBJ everything works, so I don't think the problem is there. The Buffer is to sum normals of the same vertex but from different triangles, like triangles adjacents. I really can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: But the problem could be in both parts of the code, e.g. the shader might not be robust to handle some problems with the input data (non-normalized normals for example, although I can see you are indeed normalizing them). Another test I would do is: just use the first computed normal rather than adding + normalizing, this to rule out any problem with this part of the code.

Comment: Another test to run: render a single triangle _crossing_ the `z=0` line. This will clearly show if part of the problem is in the shading or not. Also: disable specularity. In general, try to simplify the test case as much as possible, to rule out all sorts of "distractions".

Comment: I FOUND IT!!! Hi Uncle, thanks for the intrest, but I finally found the problem. It was not about anything we've said here, the shaders is perfect, the code to create normals is also pretty good, everything is OK... the problem was with the logic in my head. The solution came up when I was making some tests changing from the OBJ files to COLLADA files. In simple words, I was thinking with an OBJ logic, but using a structure like COLLADA logic. OBJ file uses normal per face, that means, if 4 vertices has the same normal 0,1,0 the OBJ file doesn't repeat this, but the COLLADA does.

Comment: The `Z=0` was a merely coincidence. Now I'm changing the parsers to right deal with this new logic and then calculate the normals correctly. Thanks again for the intrest UncleZeiv, you helped me to don't skip this problem and keep pushing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you compute per fragment lighting (i.e. if you clamp your dot product in the 0-1 range or not), what you see might just be a problem of inverted normals. Depending on how you select `A`, `B`, `C`, the normal at a vertex could point in either direction. To tell apart the outside and the inside of a triangle you usually need some more info, e.g. the winding of the vertices. Are you taking this into account?

Comment: I already tried all combinations of calculations with A,B,C... The other results are absolutely wrong...  I still searching for a solution..

Comment: I meant something sligthly different. I'm not saying you are picking up A, B, C in the wrong order. I'm saying that the order _might_ depend on some other information which could be right for half the teapot and wrong for the other half. So I wouldn't expect any particular combo to be correct in this case. Anyway, if trying all of them has not given you any additional insight, it's probably not going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Are you normalizing the result of "And then adding the normal result to an already calculated normal buffer.". I'm not sure you have to, but it won't hurt to add it. And, while your at it, check for NaN and infinity.

Do you check in your normalize function if the length of the vector coming in is bigger than 0?

I have a suspicion that you've got a nasty bug somewhere in your vector library, especially since the problem only occurs for the Z axis.

Comment: Yes man... I'm already doing all you said...  this is driving me crazy... Look, I edited the question adding some code there.